# Django migrations not applying after moving from test PC to production server/DB

Tags: python, django, migration, migrate

I am unable to run the inital migrations in my django project on my production server.

I started working on my Django app on my computer with a sqlite db. I was able to run the initial migrations (auth, admin, etc.) and they created tables in my sqlite db with no problem. I was also able to get tables created for the models in my app.

Today I moved the same django project to my webfaction server via git and I am unable to get my MySQL db populated with tables at all. As soon as I created the db, I ran migrate but it said there were no migrations to apply. I tried deleting the migrations folder in my app, but that didn't help at all, probably because there is no django_migrations table to compare any migrations against.

It seems as if the initial migrations are stored where django is installed. This is not part of my git repo, so anything there that might indicate whether the migrations have been made wouldn't be pulled over.

I tried running `python manage.py migrate admin`
And the same thing with auth, but it did't work

I'm not really sure what the proper way is to go about getting these initial migrations to run again so that I have the proper auth and admin tables in my db. Any help would be appreciated.

This is Django 2.1.7 and Python 3.5

Thanks, Yongjin and Nagesh. By asking me to post my DB settings, you made me realize that I hadn't changed the name of the DB from the project I copied the settings from. Much appreciated!

Comment: Please post your production db connection settings code in your question. Are you sure your production settings connect MySQL db?

Comment: Can you add database settings and INSTALLED_APPS settings in question.

Comment: Would you try deleting migration files if you added it in git and running `makemigrations` command before running `migrate`

Comment: Thanks guys. As I noted in my edit above, I had accidentally not changed the database name in my settings. Silly me. I had been running the migrations on another database. Thankfully all I did was add useless tables.